# Redirecting a particular user to a specific view in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have been thinking so so hard on how to go about it. I have a single registration form for all users. However, I want to redirect a particular user to a specific route but other users will be redirected to another page upon registration.
How do I tell laravel’s request method that when this particular user registers, then redirect to this specific page. But others, send them somewhere else. I have nothing in the form to indicate the user, I would like to use request to detect that user. Please someone come to my aid. Thanks.

Comment: what is your requirement .. how do you identify this particular "user"?

Comment: That’s exactly where I’m stuck. I don’t want to have any input field to identify the user but use request method to identify the user. How can I use any of the input field available to condition the registration and redirect the particular user to a specific page? Is there a workaround for such?

Comment: identify them how? how can you identify them? what conditions are you using to determine which is this particular user you are referring to?  there has to be something otherwise you wouldn't be asking for this requirement

Comment: Ok I have a single form. With fields: username, name, image, about, password and nationality. 
Upon registration, I want to redirect those from “Spain” to Spanish page, those from England to English page, France to French page and so on. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: How do I condition the “nationality field” once I grab it with the request to redirect them to particular page? Honestly that’s what I actually want to do. Grab the nationality, check it and redirect them to their respective page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `registered` method on the `RegisterController` to handle the response after the user is registered:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    // $user is the currently registered user

    if ($user->nationality == ...) {
        return redirect()->route(..., [...]);
    }

    ...

    // if that information isn't being stored on the User itself
    // you can still pull it from the Request
    //        $request->input('nationality');
}
```

An idea to get you started. Just make sure to return some type of Response from this method otherwise it will end up defaulting to its normal redirect location after registration.

You could potentially have a list of Locations to locales(assuming) that could be generated from a static array or even a database query.

```
$nationalities = [
    'Spain' => 'es',
    'England' => 'en',
    ...
];

return redirect()->route(
    'some-where', 
    ['locale' => $nationalities[$nationality] ?? 'en']
);
```

I am not sure what URLs you are trying to generate; that is just an example above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So do I declare this function before registering, saving and login the user in? Or declare it after? Oh I also want to authenticate them in the process.

Comment: this method gets ran after the user has already been registered, so they are registered and authenticated at this point ... this is just letting you handle what should happen after registration happens ... gives you finer control over what happens afterwards

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’m implementing it now. I’ll let you know the outcome.

Comment: Your code worked well. It redirected each nationality to their respective pages after several tests. But I’m doing a lot of IF’s to check their nationality which is cumbersome,  (though I’ve checked 20 nationalities and I got specific pages accordingly). I’m thinking of using switch.

Comment: switch would work just fine ... you could also make an array keyed by the nationality and the values are where you want to redirect then you could `$nationalities[$nationality] ?? 'some-default'`

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this helps - but in my app i redirect user based on roles using the following method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user_role = $request->user()->role();

    switch ($user_role) {
        case 'admin':
            return redirect('admin/home');
            break;

        case 'regular':
            return redirect('account/home');
            break;

        case 'manager':
            return redirect('manager/home');
            break;

        case 'supervisor':
            return redirect('supervisor/home');
            break;

        default:
            return redirect('account/home');
            break;
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: At - Paul Stephen Swarts... I like your suggestion but I do not have a form field for users to fill in their role. I’m conditioning the redirects from the backend with their nationalities.